# Rails: .build() does not seem to instantiate the object - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following database/model structure:

```
User -< Userorganizations >- Organization -< Organizationlocations >- Location
```

...where `-<` means: `has_many` / `belongs_to`

All of `@user.userorganizations.first.organization` (including `Organization`) is persisted (in the database).

Then, in my controller, I call:

```
@user.userorganizations.first.organization.organizationlocations.build
@user.userorganizations.first.organization.organizationlocations.first.build_location
```

...and it returns:

```
undefined method `build_location' for nil:NilClass
```

...meaning that...

```
@user.userorganizations.first.organization.organizationlocations.build
```

...did not instantiate an `Organizationlocation`.

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

The build key word does not actually instantiate the object.  As such you cannot do anything that will create a join that associates to the object that you have built until you have persisted the object in the database.

If you want to refer to the build objects you can do the following:

```
foo = @user.userorganizations.first.organization.organizationlocations.build

foo.first.build_location
```

The issue remains though that you are calling to the db but build doesn't actually create the records in the DB until you call save.

Comment: that's what I thought, but then I read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build, if you check the docs, when they do `person.pets.size  # => 5 # size of the collection`, they get the length of the builded objects, and when they do `person.pets.count # => 0 # count from database`, they get zero since nothing has been saved to the DB. Perhaps what's going on here is that since `userorganizations.first` is being called twice, those two `first`s actually are different objects ?.

Comment: It builds the objects but it does not persist them in the DB.  IF you have a join you need that object to be persisted in order to have a foreign key reference.

Comment: @ruby_newbie - Thanks, but from what I can see, you can ```build``` entire "chains" with multiple models/objects without ever persisting them in the database and still query everything as if they were persisted. For example, this here works: ```@user.userorganizations.build.build_organization.organizationlocations.build``` with only ```@user``` being persisted.

Comment: @fanta - Unfortunately, your hypothesis does not turn out to be correct, because a) there is nothing else between those 2 lines of code which could have changed the records, and b) combining the 2 lines into 1 line like so ```@user.userorganizations.first.organization.organizationlocations.build.build_location``` doesn't throw an error but it doesn't build the ```Location``` either.

Comment: @TomDogg, I think when you do `@user.userorganizations.first.organization.organizationlocations.first`, you'r getting `nil` because Rails is executing a query to the database, and it is not returning the element from the collection. Take a look at the logs when you execute that sentence.

Comment: @fanta - Well, that call *is (also) supposed to* execute a query in the DB (in my case, there is no record available btw), but then also add to the result those objects that have been instantiated in the memory (the non-persisted ones) which should have made the ```nil``` impossible in my case.

Comment: @TomDogg, looks like that's not how Rails works, I did a test myself, `.first` in an empty relationship returns whatever it finds in the database, it doesn't return the builded object, so, I'm getting the same result as you. Perhaps what you need is just to store in a variable the result of the `build` method and then use that variable for the next sentence.

Comment: I updated my answer, but as fanta suggested you need to store the built records in a variable to access them.  The reason what you are trying to do isn't working is because build doesn't persist the records and you are making a call to the db for the records.

Comment: @fanta - try this: ```user = User.new ; user.userorganizations.build ; user.userorganizations.first```. It *does* return any ```build```'ed objects : ```=> #<Userorganization id: nil, user_id: nil, organization_id: nil, role_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>```